# AUC / FPR / TPR , confused with testing vs training set

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I read a few articles related to those topic but I am still confused.

Let me try to draw something.

```
..P..p..n...P..P.|.N..N..n
```

with:

- `.` being a unknown never seen before record.
- `P` a Positive that was used during training.
- `p` a positive that was not used during training.
- `N` a negative that was used during training.
- `n` a negative that was not used during training.
- `|` the threshold where everything on the left would be marked as positive and everything on the right would be marked as negative.

And the record are ordered by the prediction from the model. The left would be the closest to `1.0` and the right to `0.0`.

From those, how do I calculate:

- `TPR` for a given threshold (`|`)
- `FPR` for a given threshold (`|`)
- `true positive` for a given threshold (`|`)
- `true negative` for a given threshold (`|`)
- `false positive` for a given threshold (`|`)
- `false negative` for a given threshold (`|`)
- and then the `ROC_AUC` value from all the points.

My confusion come from the fact that I am not sure if I should include the training sample in my `true positive`, `true negative` `false positive` `false negative` values.

If yes, then won't it be data leakage ?
And if no, then what do they count as ?

Thank you !

Comment: Machine learning tends not to care about performance on training data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide two fundamentally different things when measuring the performance of a predictive model:

- A plan how to get appropriate test cases, and
- figures of merit that measure the performance properties you are interested in.

These two are independent of each other! In other words, "we need to measure TPR" does not tell you on what kind of samples said TPR is to be measured.

One important characteristic for deciding the "data plan" is how independent the tested cases need to be from the training cases. This independence ranges from

- not independent, i.e. calculate your figures of merit from modeling residuals.
  This is appropriate only in two sitautions: when you are interested in measuring goodness-of-fit propertires, and in case the model has extremely few degrees of freedom (low complexity), say, a univariate linear regression consisting only of offset and slope and the number of training cases is large compared to the degrees of freedom (say, 10+ cases for said regression).
- The next level is routinely used: data that was not used during training, but comes from the same data set - e.g. split off in a single train/test split or by various resampling procedures such as cross validation or out-of-bootstrap flavors.
  If everything goes well, this leads to statistically independent training and test sets. But there are two situations where we don't get statistical independence with these procedures: whenever there is a clustering in the cases which we do not know of (if we know or suspect, we can split training vs. test clusters), and whenever the data set at hand is not sufficiently representative for the production data.
- The next level is to design an independent validation study. E.g. acquiring test data a certain time after training data was acquired (to check for effects of temporal drift), or e.g. at a different production facility, at different hospitals on different continets, or ...

Usually, whenever you have data available that has different levels of independence, it is best to not mix the levels into one calculation of the figures of merit but report them separately.

In your case, I'd therefore calculate the figures of merit for training and unseen cases separately, since that allows conclusions wrt. overfitting/underfitting.
If you only care for performance on unseen data, then of course you need to calculate figures of merit only for the unseen data.

Comment: Thank you ! So I would remove all of the record except `p` and `n` and run the calculation on those. Correct?

Comment: @John: yes that's correct